# How do I prove if a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a maximum, then this maximum must equal to supremum?

Tags: real-analysis

I am taking an introduction to real analysis class. In class, my professor proves the maximum of a non-empty finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$, if exists, is equal to the supremum in the following way:

Say we have $S$ is the subset meets all the requirements. Let $s_1=\max S, s_2=\sup S.$

*First part:* $s_1$ is the element of $S$, then $s1\leq \sup S=s_2,$ thus $s_1\leq s_2.$

*Second part:* $s_1>s$, for all, $s \in S$, then $s_1$ is an upper bound for $S$, **thus $s1\geq s_2$.**

Therefore, $s_1=s_2.$

> I understand everything about this proof except the end of the second part. How can we conclude $s_1\geq s_2$ based on the fact s1 is an upper bound? Isn't $s_1$ in the subset, whereas $s_2$ can be in and out? The definition of upper bound says that this upper bound is greater and equal to all the elements in the subset. So do we just assume $s_2$ in the subset?

Sorry for my formatting, I am pretty new to this platform and still learning. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Here's a MathJax [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Just check that maximum meets the criteria for supremum. The concept of a supremum is non-trivial only in case there is no maximum.

Comment: It's simply that any upper bound ($s_1$) can't be less than the *least* upper bound ($s_2$). That's what "least" means. And "can't be less than" means "is greater than or equal to".

Answer (score 1):

Supremum of a set is the **least** upper bound. So if $s_1$ is an upper bound, and $s_2$ is the supremum, then $s_2 \leq s_1.$

This is irrespective of whether $s_2$ is an element of $S$ or not.

Comment: Make sense! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

If $s_1$ is the maximum of $S$ then

- $s_1 \ge s, \forall s \in S$
- so $s_1$ is an upper bound of $S$
- so $s_1 \ge s_2$, the supremum (i.e. least upper bound) of $S$

Comment: Thank you so much!!